# Administrator password lost for late 2013 MacBook Pro with Yosemite

Tags: password, administrator, macos

An ex-employee change her administrator password when she was fired and nobody can access the MacBook Pro (late 2013 model). It is running on Yosemite. I have tried using the Command/S key to change it, but it does not work. What can I do to restore the computer and set-up a new administrator?

Comment: See my answer here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/144425/62132

Answer (score 1):

First of all - restart your computer. Press the **Command** and **R** keys at the same time when the grey screen appears and hold them until you see the Apple logo. A small loading bar will appear under the logo. Sit tight as your system boots into Recovery Mode.

Click the Utilities tab in the top menu bar, select Terminal, type **resetpassword** and press Enter. Close out the Terminal window and behind it you will find the Reset Password utility. All you have to do now is select the user account you want to reset, enter a new password or leave it blank and click Save. Then just simply restart the computer from the Apple menu and login with your new password.

However if the user was protected by FileVault or Firmware password, you will probably need to clean-install OSX.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, and I left the password blank, and saved it. I restarted and it is still asking for the Administrator's iCloud password. I redid it again and added a new password, and the same thing happened. Still can't get on computer with the new password! What now?